# Update an existing collection in MongoDB using Java-Hadoop connector

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce, mongodb-hadoop

Is it possible to update existing MongoDB collection with new data. I am using hadoop job to read write data to Mongo. Required scenario is :- 
Say first collection in Mongo is

```
{ 
  "_id" : 1,
  "value" : "aaa"
  "value2" : null
}
```

after reading data from Mongo and processing data, MongoDB should contain

```
{ 
  "_id" : 1,
  "value" : "aaa"
  "value2" : "bbb"
}
```

If possible, please provide some dummy code.

Comment: Can't you use a simple update with a $set basicDBObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it by extending `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordWriter` and overriding write method of this class.

Answer (score 3):

```
BasicBSONObject query=new BasicBSONObject();
query.append("fieldname", value);
BasicBSONObject update=new BasicBSONObject();

update.append("$set", new BasicBSONObject().append("newfield",value));
MongoUpdateWritable muw=new MongoUpdateWritable(query,update,false,true);
contex.write(key, muw);
```

**query** : is used for providing condition(matching condition).

**update** : is used for adding new field and value in existing collection.

**MongoUpdateWritable**:
3rd parameter is upsert value(same as mongodb)

4th parameter is multiple update in many documents in a collection.

Set in Driver class
  **`job.setOutputValueClass(MongoUpdateWritable.class);`**

Answer (score 0):

The Mongo-Hadoop Connector doesn't currently suppor this feature.  You can open a feature request in the [MongoDB Jira](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP) if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by the [stratio](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB), if you are using spark, you can check it out!